# Nagios memory free plug-in misbehaving after upgrade to Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, monitoring, nagios

We use Nagios here for monitoring our servers.

On the test network I upgraded to Debian 9/Stretch, the memory monitoring box/object in our Nagios monitoring platform says CRITICAL and next to it, CHECK_MEMORY CRITICAL - Unable to interpret /usr/bin/free output.

The problem is in several servers; the check is done via a remote plug-in installed with the agent. What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have followed the problem, as in:

```
$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_memory
MEMORY CRITICAL - Unable to interpret /usr/bin/free output
```

What I found is the output of the `free` command in `procps` changed the output format.

```
$free -m
```

old format:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3011       1415       1596          4         24        162
-/+ buffers/cache:       1228       1783
Swap:         1023          0       1023
```

new format:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3012        1132         140           0        1739        1703
Swap:          1063           0        1063
```

The plug-in in question is installed in `nagios-plugins-contrib`.

```
$dpkg -S  /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_memory
nagios-plugins-contrib: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_memory
```

There also has been a bug report about it here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=806598

However `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_memory` in the package `nagios-plugins-contrib` has not been adjusted to the new `free` output in Debian Stretch.

Apparently there is a patch here in the meanwhile: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=806598;filename=check_memory_new_free_output.patch;msg=5